# How long it takes for the Falcon 9 payload fairings to reach the sea?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, reuse, fairings

The payload fairings of Falcon 9 are released at about 3:15 min

How much time they need to fall and reach the sea?

And what is their maximum speed while reentry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the answer is about 40 minutes but I do not have a source handy.  Looking.